# Nextjs: Pass state in routes via router.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

//1st Page

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Input from "../components/Input";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Add = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    LastName: "",
  });
  const onSubmited = (data) => {
    setForm({
      firstName: data.firstName,
      lastName: data.lastName,
    });
    router.push({
      pathname: "/",
      query: { firstName: data.firstName, lastName: data.lastName },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(form);
  }, [form]);

  return (
    <div>
      Form
      <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push("/")}>
        Back to homepage
      </button>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmited)}>
        <label>First name</label>
        <Input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="First Name" />
        <label>Last name</label>
        <Input {...register("lastName")} placeholder="Last Name" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

//2nd page:

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BasicTable from "../app/(pages)/components/BasicTable";
import axios from "axios";

import Link from "next/link";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const Home = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeData = () => {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response) => setData(response.data));
    };
    initializeData();
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    {
      id: 1,
      header: "userId",
      accessorKey: "userId",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      header: "Id",
      accessorKey: "id",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      header: "body",
      accessorKey: "body",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      header: "title",
      accessorKey: "title",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => router.push("/Add")}>
        Add to
      </button>
      <BasicTable columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The data that i'm getting from the inputs will be stored inside 'form' state. After the form has been submitted, the user will be route to another page. What i want is that when the page submitted, i want to bring the form state to the next page. on the 2nd page, i will store the form state to a useEffect api so that it will update the data of the table and will include the new data from the form. i'm getting errors of TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function